# Why is aggregation on a string field faster than aggregation on an int field?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a table with the following columns:

```
.create-merge table events
(
  Time: datetime,
  SiteId: int,
  SiteCode: string,
  ...
)
```

Site ID and code both provide unique value for a site, theoretically it does not matter which one to use unless I need certain data type in the output. However I see a noticeable difference in performance between the queries:

```
events | summarize count() by SiteCode
~ 300 ms on a 150M rows table
```

```
events | summarize count() by SiteId
~ 560 ms on a 150M rows table
```

The difference is small in the absolute value, but the string one is almost two times faster than the integer one (for consistent results, I issue requests from a client in the same region). The string code consists of 10-20 characters and intuitively seems to have larger footprint in the computer memory as opposed to 4-byte integer, hence I would expect longer processing of the string one, but it works conversely.

What could be the reason for that? I am missing something fundamental from ADX internals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using EngineV3, you are seeing the impact of the dictionary encoding optimization implemented in this engine, where in certain cases string values are encoded to small and efficient int values, hence the better performance. As EngineV3 continues to improve this optimization may be added to int values as well.

Comment: Yes, that's V3. But int is already int, isn't it? How is encoding int different from original int? I am trying to follow...

Comment: The Engine is written in Rust, you can see here the different int types that Rust offers: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/365/getting-started-with-rust/primitive-data-types (int8, int16, int32, int64), what I am saying is that the int used for dictionary encoding and its efficiency compared with regular index explains the perf difference you are seeing or in other words, what you are seeing is correct and by design (for now) -:)